# How to get singular result response from Postman Test loops

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs, postman

I am a manual QA and I started learning postman and API testing, I have no programming background so if my tests give you anxiety I am truly sorry.

In any case, my resonse body is JSON with multiple objects (I guess they are objects?), the examples I will post are from a testing API.

URL/URI:
https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2

```
bodyData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

console.warn(bodyData.data.length);
broj = bodyData.data.length;
console.log(broj);

pm.environment.set("Ime", bodyData.data[3].first_name)  
// this one is just added here to have an environment value for comparison

for (i = 0; i < broj; i++)
{
    //pm.test("Body is correct BAJRON", function () {
    //pm.response.to.have.body("Byron");
    
    pm.test("A A A A A A A A A B A  J R ON : " + pm.environment.get("Ime"), function(){
    pm.expect(bodyData.data[i].first_name).to.eql("Byron");

});
}
```

This loop logs out 6 answers of which 4th one having Byron is green.
What I want is if ANY of these results are green, have the test log the whole for loop tests as if they passed because the purpose of the test is to find a certain object.

Thanks :)